# How to combine multiple homogenous tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join

I'm wondering how I'd go about joining the following tables together, I have two questions which have been asked, across two collection years.  I want to collate the results.  Note that followUp will be constant for everyone in the table.

```
Q1YR1
SubjectNo FollowUp  Response
1         1         Yes
2         1         No

Q2YR1
SubjectNo FollowUp  Response
1         1         No
2         1         Yes

Q2YR2
SubjectNo FollowUp  Response
1         2         Yes
2         2         Yes

Q2YR2
SubjectNo FollowUp  Response
1         2         No
2         2         No
```

I'm trying to get to the following:

```
SubjectNo FollowUp Q1YR1 Q2YR1 Q1YR2 Q2YR2
1         1        Yes   No
1         2                    Yes   No
2         1        No    Yes
2         2                    Yes   No
```

So far I've taken a union of the tables:

```
(SELECT subjectno_0 AS SubjectNo, aiw_0 AS Age, followup_0 AS FollowUp, dataresponse_0 AS Q1YR1, NULL AS Q2YR1, NULL AS Q1YR2, NULL AS Q2YR2 FROM question1yr1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT subjectno_0 AS SubjectNo, aiw_0 AS Age, followup_0 AS FollowUp, NULL AS Q1YR1, dataresponse_0 AS Q2YR1, NULL AS Q1YR2, NULL AS Q2YR2 FROM question2yr1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT subjectno_0 AS SubjectNo, aiw_0 AS Age, followup_0 AS FollowUp, NULL AS Q1YR1, NULL AS Q2YR1, dataresponse_0 AS Q1YR2, NULL AS Q2YR2 FROM question1yr2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT subjectno_0 AS SubjectNo, aiw_0 AS Age, followup_0 AS FollowUp, NULL AS Q1YR1, NULL AS Q2YR1, NULL AS Q1YR2, dataresponse_0 AS Q2YR2 FROM question2yr2)
```

Which gets me half way there, but obviously doesn't join responses by SubjectNo and FollowUp.  I've tried self joining, but I can't seem to get it quite right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this situation is finding the set of all subject numbers and followups that exist.  If you know what that is (lets say it is a table called subjectnumber) this is a simple left join:

```
SELECT SN.SubjectNo, SN.FollowUp,
  Q1YR1.Response AS Q1YR1,
  Q2YR1.Response AS Q2YR1, 
  Q1YR2.Response AS Q1YR2,
  Q2YR2.Response AS Q2YR2
FROM SubjectNumber SN
LEFT JOIN Q1YR1 ON SN.SubjectNo = Q1YR1.SubjectNo AND SN.FollowUp = Q1YR1.FollowUp
LEFT JOIN Q2YR1 ON SN.SubjectNo = Q2YR1.SubjectNo AND SN.FollowUp = Q2YR1.FollowUp 
LEFT JOIN Q1YR2 ON SN.SubjectNo = Q1YR2.SubjectNo AND SN.FollowUp = Q1YR2.FollowUp
LEFT JOIN Q2YR2 ON SN.SubjectNo = Q2YR2.SubjectNo AND SN.FollowUp = Q2YR2.FollowUp
```

If you don't have one of these subject numbers tables then you have to make one from your incident tables using union like this:

```
SELECT SN.SubjectNo, SN.FollowUp,
  Q1YR1.Response AS Q1YR1,
  Q2YR1.Response AS Q2YR1, 
  Q1YR2.Response AS Q1YR2,
  Q2YR2.Response AS Q2YR2
FROM (
  SELECT SubjectNo, FollowUp FROM Q1R1 UNION
  SELECT SubjectNo, FollowUp FROM Q2R1 UNION
  SELECT SubjectNo, FollowUp FROM Q1R2 UNION
  SELECT SubjectNo, FollowUp FROM Q2R2 
) SN
LEFT JOIN Q1YR1 ON SN.SubjectNo = Q1YR1.SubjectNo AND SN.FollowUp = Q1YR1.FollowUp
LEFT JOIN Q2YR1 ON SN.SubjectNo = Q2YR1.SubjectNo AND SN.FollowUp = Q2YR1.FollowUp 
LEFT JOIN Q1YR2 ON SN.SubjectNo = Q1YR2.SubjectNo AND SN.FollowUp = Q1YR2.FollowUp
LEFT JOIN Q2YR2 ON SN.SubjectNo = Q2YR2.SubjectNo AND SN.FollowUp = Q2YR2.FollowUp
```